# Можно ли заставить рендерить приложение определенной видеокартой?

Tags: железо

В обще, такая проблема:
Есть видеокарта GeForce 1660 SUPER к которой подключен основной монитор и на котором я запускаю тяжелые графические приложения (игры). Так же есть второй монитор и ТВ, которые подключены к ПК через интегрированную видеокарту INTEL HD Graphics 4000, так как на видеокарте нету разъема HDMI и старенького DVI, а перехондники не хочу покупать.

Все работает, но, если я делаю основным монитором свой ТВ, чтобы игра запустилась во весь экран на нем, то она рендерится через интегрированную карточку...

Можно ли как-то решить эту проблему?

Вроде, в глобальных настройках я все настроил, чтобы рендер был через GeForce, но не работает =(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]